# Flex Glow effect customization

Tags: apache-flex, effects

I use Flex's `Glow` effects in my custom `VBox`-based component for highlighting it on roll over. It looks great. But I would like it to have rectangular shape with gradient to alpha 0. How can I accomplish that? Should I add some properties to Glow effect or mix it somehow with other effects or use another effect?

Code is below:

```
<mx:VBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" rollOverEffect="{select}" rollOutEffect="{deselect}">
    <!-- Some stuff skipped -->
    <mx:Glow id="select" duration="500">
        <mx:color>#9BC227</mx:color>
        <mx:blurXFrom>100</mx:blurXFrom>                
        <mx:blurXTo>100</mx:blurXTo>
        <mx:blurYFrom>100</mx:blurYFrom>
        <mx:blurYTo>100</mx:blurYTo>
        <mx:alphaFrom>0</mx:alphaFrom>
        <mx:alphaTo>1</mx:alphaTo>
    </mx:Glow>
    <mx:Glow id="deselect" duration="1000">
        <mx:color>#9BC227</mx:color>
        <mx:blurXFrom>100</mx:blurXFrom>                
        <mx:blurXTo>0</mx:blurXTo>
        <mx:blurYFrom>100</mx:blurYFrom>
        <mx:blurYTo>0</mx:blurYTo>
        <mx:alphaFrom>1</mx:alphaFrom>
        <mx:alphaTo>0</mx:alphaTo>
     </mx:Glow>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an `mx.effects` class that wraps it up with a tween, but there is a [GradientGlowFilter](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/filters/GradientGlowFilter.html) class in [flash.filters](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/filters/package-detail.html).  All `Glow` does is return a `GlowInstance`, which when played applies a series of `Glow` filters using a tween.  The code is very simple, and you could modify it to use a different filter pretty easily.